# return method response after it executes to the parent method

Tags: php, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I am using xmlprc server in codeignter for web services . the flow of my application is that i need to pass parameters to the xmlrpc server method which then should invoke another controller class method which would set the parameters in a js function and that js method is invoked concurrently .
The problem i am facing is in calling the controller class method from the xmlrpc server method and getting the response to the server parent method which could then be fetched using xmlhttprequest.

my xmlrpc server method is:

```
 function update_p($request) {
 $parameters = $request->output_parameters();
 $this->session->set_userdata(array("portfolio" =>$parameters['0']["portfolio"]));
 $this->session->set_userdata(array("filter" =>$parameters['0']["filter"]));

          $url  = base_url("ControllerClass/update_p?".$parameters['0']["portfolio"].'&'.$parameters['0']["filter"]);
           header("Location: $url");

    $xml_rpc_rows=array("portfolio"=>$parameters['0']["portfolio"],"filter"=>$parameters['0']["filter"]);



        $response = array(
            $xml_rpc_rows,
            'struct');
         $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);



    }
```

Controller Class method:

```
public function update_p() {
        $loginid = $this->session->userdata('loginid');
        if(!isset($loginid)){
            die;
        }
        error_reporting(E_ERROR);
        if (time()>$this->session->userdata('expire')) { redirect("/dashboard/logout?expired=Y","location",401); die; }

        $out='';

        $request="USER ".$loginid.($this->session->userdata('isMobile')?"@mobile":"")."\n";


        if(isset($_GET["portfolio"])) {
            $portfolio=trim($_GET["portfolio"]);
            $request.='ECHO "LISTP":'."\nLISTP0 #".$portfolio;
            if(isset($_GET["filter"])) {
                $filter=trim($_GET["filter"]);
                $request.=" -".$filter;
            }
            if(isset($_GET["sort"])) {
                $sort=trim($_GET["sort"]);
                if ($sort>=1024) $request.=" -s".($sort&1023);
                else $request.=" -S".$sort;
            }
            $ph = isset($_GET["first"]);
            if ($ph) { 
                $this->load->model('Model');
                $resultArray = $this->Model->getData($this->session->userdata('loginid'),$this->session->userdata('isMobile')?'mobile':'default','listp');
                $request.=" ".$resultArray[0]['listp'];
            }
            $request.="\nECHO ,\n";
            if(isset($_GET["watch"])) {
                $portfolio=trim($_GET["watch"]);
                if ($ph)
                    $resultArray = $this->Model->getData($this->session->userdata('loginid'),$this->session->userdata('isMobile')?'mobile':'default','watch');
                $request.='ECHO "watchl":'."\nLISTP1 #".$portfolio." -WL ".($ph?$resultArray[0]['watch']:"")."\n";
                $request.='ECHO ,"watchs":'."\nLISTP1 #".$portfolio." -WS\nECHO ,\n";
            }
        }
        $request.="RISk\nECHO ,\nPnL\n";

        if ($result=$this->getData($request."BYE\n")) {
            if (result!='') $out=$result."\n";
        }

        ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
        echo "{".$out."}";
        ob_end_flush();

    }
```

I can not figure out how to get the controller method result in the server method anyone who can shed some light on this would be much appreciated .
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method is expecting to output the result as an echo statement, which goes to the browser, rather than to return it in a variable. This means your server function is having to try to capture the output of that controller method. That setup is much more awkward and prone to error.

Unless you also need to access your update_p method directly from a browser you should change your Controller to simply return the output which really means this controller is more of a library and should probably go in the libraries folder. You will need to change your controller code a bit so that instead of grabbing the parameters from $_GET you are getting them as arguments, which in CodeIgniter is what you should be doing anyway.

So from the end of update_p just do this instead of your echo:

```
return "{".$out."}";
```

Then in your xmlrpc server do this:

```
$controller = new ControllerClass();
$result = $controller->update_p($parameters['0']["portfolio"], $parameters['0']["filter"]);
```

Then do whatever you want with your $result.